# After Upgrade from TYPO3 8.7 to 9.5 I cannot edit my records

Tags: typo3

After updating my TYPO3 to 9.5 LTS from 8.7 LTS, When trying to edit a content element. I have been running all the relevant Update Wizards. I get:

```
Oops, an error occurred!
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "wizard_element_browser" because this route was not found.
```

The is also happening when trying to add new content elements.

When I use the Page Module I see the content in the expected columns, and with the correct connect.

The list view is also not working for me after updating..

Formatting the stack trace here, isn't super easy, so added a gist.
https://gist.github.com/tomasnorre/17ea65ed60f6877801e9260ac316d76e

Comment: The same error come when i Click "Add new site configuration for this site"

Comment: And if I try to edit Page Properties

Comment: The same goes for Editing a Backend User.

Comment: Even if it seems to be solved individually, it would be great to get the debug output and detailed information of which exception is thrown at which place. In order to do that, please enable the "debug preset" in the install tool...

Comment: I don't have the Stack-trace anymore, but I'm trying to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is some guesswork without a full stack trace.

First some background:

The route that is not found is registered in `typo3/sysext/recordlist/Configuration/Backend/Routes.php`.

The Backend routes are initialized in the `initializeBackendRouter()` method in `typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php` and they are cached.

So the first explanation would be, that for some reason the configuration file is missing or the recordlist Extension is not loaded / available.

The second explanation would be a caching problem. Please try to clear all caches using the admin tools and clearing `typo3temp` and `var/cache` folders.

The third explanation would be some Extension that accesses the route too early in the bootstrap process before the route is registered.

If nothing of this helps, please enable debugging in the admin tools (Settings -> Configuration Presets -> Debug) an uncomment this line in the `.htaccess` to enable the Development context:

```
RewriteRule .? - [E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]
```

You can then post the stacktrace back here and we try to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. 

The problem was that the filelist extension wasn't correctly installed.. 

I haven't payed attention to that it was light grey and not black text.

I was simply adding it manually to the PackagesStates.php 

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.